# Map union type into type with argument

Tags: typescript

I have a union type looking like this

`type Union = "a"|"b"|"c"`

From this type, i want to create a new type that takes each of the possible union values as arguments. Like this:

`type NewType = MySpecialType<"a">|MySpecialType<"b">|MySpecialType<"c">`

Is there a way to map my `Union` type into `NewType`?

I can do this manually but the type I'm working with will potentially grow quite a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a self-indexed [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
type Union = "a"|"b"|"c"

type MySpecialType<U extends Union> = { u: U };

type NewType = { [U in Union]:  MySpecialType<U> }[Union];

const a: NewType = { u: 'a' };
const b: NewType = { u: 'b' };
const c: NewType = { u: 'c' };
```

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=31&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZygXigIgIaYD6YBG+mAxpgFAWiRQCyIAypKQtgDYAq4EAPDFAgAPYBDgATAM6xEKAHzooAbygBXAFywoAXwDcVGtAByEAO7daGFQG0BCVPGRwAupvpMWbLj34Ltt2Rd9ClIUSWAobE0Tcx5FFQ0oAHJsJJ19ULhwqEJoswtoKzVNJMI0vRCwiNI82MtlYuTSct0gA)</sup>

Here, `NewType` will be resolved as follows:

```
type NewType = MySpecialType<"a"> | MySpecialType<"b"> | MySpecialType<"c">
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way is to use [distributive-conditional-types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)

```js
type Union = "a" | "b" | "c"

type MySpecialType<U> = { u: U };

type Distribute<T> = T extends any ? MySpecialType<T> : never

type NewType = Distribute<Union>

const a: NewType = { u: 'a' };
const b: NewType = { u: 'b' };
const c: NewType = { u: 'c', };
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w6Ld0m)